# Many-To-Many movie director system

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following relationship in EF Core 3.1.1 (Many-To-Many):

```
public partial class Movie
{
    public Movie()
    {
        Directors = new HashSet<MovieDirector>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MovieDirector> Directors { get; set; }
}

public partial class Director
{
    public Director()
    {
        MovieDirector = new HashSet<MovieDirector>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MovieDirector> MovieDirector { get; set; }
}

public partial class MovieDirector
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public string DirectorId { get; set; }

    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public virtual Director Director { get; set; }
}
```

And I have the following method to create a `Director`:

```
public Director CreateDirector(int movieId, Director director)
{
    var movie = _repository.Movie.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Id == movieId);

    movie.Directors.Add(new MovieDirector{ Director = director });

    _repository.SaveChanges();

    return director;
}
```

The `CreateDirector` method can perfectly create a new `Director` including relationships.

My biggest question is if every time I need to insert in a table that has a relationship I will need:

1. Find the parent/root entity (`Movie`)
2. Create a new `MovieDirector` object
3. Associate the new `MovieDirector` object with the parent/root, like:

   ```
   movie.Directors.Add(new MovieDirector)
   ```

Is this correct or is there some kind of shortcut?

Comment: This is a One-To-Many relationship not Many-To-Many. Or can the same Review reference to many Movies?

Comment: @keuleJ The example was Many-To-Many, but the context no! One review belong to one Movie. I change the context sample! ;)

Comment: Why are all of these `partial class`? Also, `CreateDirector` doesn't do what you say it does. The director is already created and passed as an argument, the method creates a `MovieDirector` and then returns the director for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you know the id value of the movie the new director should be associated with. That makes it easy to set the relationships without pulling the entire movie entity from the database:

```cs
public Director CreateDirector(int movieId, Director director)
{
    director.MovieDirectors.Add(new MovieDirector { MovieId = movieId });

    _repository.Add(director);
    _repository.SaveChanges();

    return director;
}
```

You may need another repository type, but the code you show isn't conclusive on that.

Answer (score 1):

When two entities are related in many-to-many relationship, neither of them are a parent/root entity nor a dependent/child entity. They are two individual entities totally independent of each other. They are related, but neither of them depends on the other.

At database level a parent/child dependency is mapped through a foreign-key. For a many-to-many relationship there is no foreign-key involved, and the relationship is mapped through a joining table, which we model with a joining entity at code level, (the `MovieDirector` entity in your example).

So, if `Director` and `Movie` are in a many-to-many relationship, then `Movie` is by no means a parent entity of `Director`, or vice-versa. Therefore, you should always be able to create a `Director` entity independent of any information referencing any movie. And from that perspective I see a major flaw in your code - currently you cannot create a `Director` entity independently, you need a `movieId` for that (which you shouldn't).

Think about a possible scenario where you might need to select one or more directors while creating a new movie, and that might be the first time some of those directors gets linked with a movie. What I'm trying to imply is, you can always have a director, or want to create one, for whom there is no movie in the database.

The signature of your `CreateDirector` method should be like -

```cs
public Director CreateDirector(Director director)
```

First setup any related entities (if there is any) before reaching the `CreateDirector` method -

```cs
director.MovieDirectors.Add(new MovieDirector { MovieId = movieId });
```

and then call for creating the new director -

```cs
public Director CreateDirector(Director director)
{
    _repository.Directors.Add(director);
    _repository.SaveChanges();
    return director;
}
```

Now you can create a director independently or, along with its related entities. I hope that simplifies your current approach too.